# If Then Else won't initiate vbNo

Tags: vbscript

This code is supposed to open a script to simulate a timer when "Yes" is pressed or open a script to simulate an alarm when "No" is pressed. When "Yes" is pressed it works as intended, but when "No" is pressed, it still opens the timer script and not the alarm one.

```
Pick = MsgBox("Do you want a Timer?", 4+32, "Choose one")
If vbYes Then
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\Username\Documents\Applications\Reminder\Reminder Script.vbs""")
    WScript.Quit
Else
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\Username\Documents\Applications\Alarm\Alarm Script.vbs""")
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

Comment: I'm new to VBScript so please explain yourself

Comment: You might want to somehow use in the comparison the variable into which you store the result of `MsgBox`.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: `if Pick = vbYes then`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can do this two ways (See below - please excuse the syntax). The If...Then...Else method is answered by *GSerg* and *pinkfloydx33* in the comments to your question...

```
set wshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

'**If...Then...Else**

pick = msgbox("Do you want a timer?", 4+32, "Choose one")
if pick = vbyes then
'wshell.run("""c:\users\username\documents\applications\reminder\reminder script.vbs""")
wscript.echo "Reminder"
else
'whsell.run("""c:\users\username\documents\applications\alarm\alarm script.vbs""")
wscript.echo "Alarm"
end if

'**Select...Case**

pick = msgbox("Do you want a timer?", 4+32, "Choose one")
select case pick
case vbyes
'wshell.run("""c:\users\username\documents\applications\reminder\reminder script.vbs""")
wscript.echo "Reminder"
wscript.quit
case vbno
'whsell.run("""c:\users\username\documents\applications\alarm\alarm script.vbs""")
wscript.echo "Alarm"
wscript.quit
end select
```

Hopefully this helps.

Furthermore the [MSDN VBScript User guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84).aspx) may help better explain variables etc.